# ReplaceAll function in Actionscript

Tags: string, actionscript-3, flash

Is there a way in Actionscript to do replaceall? For example:

```
Array[hi,tom,fcuk,xes]

SomeString.replace(Array,"*")
```

So basically, it shall replace all the array words with *.

Thanks!

Comment: Use the array `.map` method

Comment: or the arr.forEach() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So basically, it shall replace all the array words with *.

Simple and fast iteration will help you ;)

```
function replaceAll(list:Array, value:*):void {
    var i:uint, len:uint = list.length;

    for (i; i < len; ++i) {
        //any logic you want go here...
        list[i] = value;
    }
}

var test: Array = ["hi","tom","fcuk","xes"];
replaceAll(test, "*")
trace(test); //*,*,*,*
```

> replace words from an existing string

```
//Words to replace, use word boundary to chop full words (\b + wordToSearch + \b)
//Or construct it from Array
var badWords: RegExp =  /Lorem|ipsum|\bin\b/g;
var text: String = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vix te purto eros inimicus, per omnes admodum assentior ne, vis ei autem affert. At adhuc splendide definiebas per, dico soluta aliquid id mea. Agam probo nostrum mel in. Dicunt splendide ex eum. Te viris minimum elaboraret cum. Sed ea essent vidisse vituperata.";
trace(text.replace(badWords, "***"));
```

Remove Urls:

```
var urlPattern: RegExp = /(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9_%]*)\b\.[a-z]{2,4}(\.[a-z]{2})?((\/[a-zA-Z0-9_%]‌​*)+)?(\.[a-z]*)?/gi;
var someTextWithUrls: String = "Well, the way someurl.com they make shows is, http://simpleurl.it they make one show. That shows called a pilot. isiturl.im";
trace(someTextWithUrls.replace(urlPattern, "***")); //Well, the way *** they make shows is, *** they make one show. That shows called a pilot. ***
```

Comment: Thanks for a prompt reply. However, this is function will not replace Array words from an existing string. COuld you add that?

Comment: I just have a small question. How can I replace URLS?

Comment: Same, add to the regular expression, expression for the URL finding, do you want strip all urls, or classic? For example: `http[s]?:[^\s]*`

Comment: And this one, ugly one, will find any Urls... `(https?://)?(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9_%]*)\b\.[a-z]{2,4}(\.[a-z]{2})?((/[a-zA-Z0-9_%]*)+)?(\.[a-z]*)?`

Comment: What do you mean by classic? I just want to replace any URL with *

Comment: If you want any, you will need last one, that I have posted.

Comment: I tried this but its not working: var nourl: RegExp = new RegExp("(https?://)?(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9_%]*)\b\.[a-z]{2,4}(\.[a-z]{2})?((/[a-zA-Z0-9_%]‌​*)+)?(\.[a-z]*)?","gi");
           if(nourl.test(msg)){

Comment: By the way, your answer is in more detail so I am going to keep the best answer option open for now.

Comment: I have added for removing urls.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am having some trouble with badWords example. It does not replace. Do I need to add \bword\b|\bword2\b|? It does not replace any of the word. What is \bin? and why there is only one \b?

Comment: `\b`- is a boundary of the word, `|` - is an OR. My example is working. It looks for three words: `Lorem`, `impsum` and `in`. `in` defined as word by the help of `\b`, so It will find only `in` in text, and not a typing, selecting, inner

Answer (score 0):

```
var somestring:String = "a111b222c333";
var replacelist:Array = ["a","b","c"];

for each(var str:String in replacelist)
{
while (somestring.search(str) != -1) somestring = somestring.replace(str, "*");
}

trace (somestring);  // *111*222*333
```

Comment: Your welcome. Also it may be solved with "RegEX" stuff. You could make a search on the internet about "RegEX", it may solve your problem "in a single line of code", i think. But it's some complicated stuff. (But it doesn't make your work more easy if you have to use "array")

Comment: I just have a small question. How can I replace URLS?

Comment: What kind of a replacement?

Comment: I want if any message (String) contains any URL, it should be replaced. Right now I am making a check on www and http but it is not a clean solution.

Comment: you can replace url if it containing some specific stuff like "http" or "www" but, i don't think you can replace something like ==> "ASDASDwww.xxx.comUYUY" but you can replace "ASDSD www.xxx.com UADASD". I mean, need some spaces between url and other stuff i think.